# Integrate acts_as_rated plugin in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rating

I am creating a user-boards applicationin rails in which a user owns any number of boards and can **rate** the boards.I want to install **acts_as_rated** plugin in my rails application. Since this is not available as a gem i have used following command to install it as a plugin:

```
rails plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/acts-as-rated/trunk/acts_as_rated
```

This command installs all required plugin files in the vendor directory. Next I include the following code in my **Boards** model

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_rated
end
```

Next i restart my console and run the following commands

```
u=User.first
 => #<User id: 1, first_name: "taroon", created_at: "2012-03-26 09:18:20", updated_at: "2012-03-26 09:18:20">

b=Board.first
 => #<Board id: 1, name: "boards_1", created_at: "2012-03-26 09:19:39", updated_at: "2012-03-26 09:19:39"> 

b.rate 5, u
```

It gives me the following **error**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'ratings'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:295:in `table_structure'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:186:in `columns'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:685:in `columns'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:698:in `column_names'
from /home/swati/projects/test_projects/dummy_project/vendor/plugins/acts_as_rated/lib/acts_as_rated.rb:193:in `rate'
from (irb):6
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I checked out the migartion but no migration for **rating** tables was created. Neither I have an idea of the fields in this table.

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README of [act_as_rated](https://github.com/jasherai/acts-as-rated) plugin says that you need to do your own migration based on this file: `test/fixtures/migrations/001_add_rating_tables.rb`.

Quote from the README:

> The file `test/fixtures/migrations/001_add_rating_tables.rb`
>   shows examples of all types of migration options.
>
> See also the detailed documentation for the acts_as_rated
>   method on how to declare it, and the rest of the documentation for how
>   to generate the migration columns/files and how to use it.

So download and extract your module from [here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=3011), then you can find the corresponding file and you can do your own migration.